# NoClassDefFoundError for aurora.jar

Tags: java, class

I am trying to execute next:

```
C:\dev\sources\boSchedules\loadJavaLibs>java -cp aurora.jar; ojdbc6.jar
oracle.aurora.server.tools.loadjava.LoadJavaMain -thin -user login/pass@myserv:mysid
 %BOS_SRC%/credit/card/api/ScheduleCardApi
```

And I get next:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: ojdbc6/jar
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ojdbc6.jar
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: ojdbc6.jar.  Program will exit.
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Don't put a space after the `;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [Java Application Launcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/java.html) man page.

```
java -cp aurora.jar; ojdbc6.jar
oracle.aurora.server.tools.loadjava.LoadJavaMain -thin -user sched/sched@teach:prod
 %BOS_SRC%/credit/card/api/ScheduleCardApi
```

You have a space between your classpath entries `aurora.jar; ojdbc6.jar`. The launcher thinks the first jar is the only classpath entry and the `ojdbc6.jar` is your class containing the `main(String[] args)` method. It also considers everything after that as arguments to pass to the `main(String[] args)` method. Remove that space.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the space between the aurora.jar; and the ojdbc6.jar

Answer (score 1):

Spaces delimit the parameters each other. The JVM interprets the command as if you run "ojdbc6.jar" class: "jar" as a classname and "ojdbc6" as a package.

To concat the names of libraries you want to place into classpath for a specific class run please use semicolon with no spaces as "lib1;lib2"

**P.S.:** Could you please ask your colleagues if you may paste some of our credentials to the SO? :)